# Drag and Drop items Within a gridview

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there any way, drag and drop items in same Gridview for reordering the items?

I visited these examples but in both examples drag and drop allows items in different GridViews.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/16/drag-and-drop-within-a-grouped-grid-view.aspx

http://www.renauddumont.be/en/2012/windows-8-csharp-xaml-drag-drop

I am trying to drag and drop items in same Gridview for reordering the items.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these lines in GridView XAML

```
            CanReorderItems="True"
            AllowDrop="True"
            CanDragItems="True"
```

Comment: It seems don't support reordering, the dropped item always at the last

Comment: @James This should help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388867/xaml-c-what-event-fires-after-reordering-a-gridview

Basically, ObservableCollection<T> should do all reordering for you.

Comment: @ShashankBisen for Windows Phone 8.1, you do use `.ReorderMode=ListViexReorderMode.Enabled` ! Look here : [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/elibrary/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.reordermode.aspx[/link]