# XAML/C#: What event fires after reordering a gridview?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am making my first Windows Store app in Visual Studios 2012. I have a gridview control that I have enabled to be reordered. I have code that I need to run when the list is reordered. I have tried the Drop event. It does not fire. I tried several other drag events, which also did not fire. It seems like this should be so simple... Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can use `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection<T>`, if you have provided `ItemsSource` of `GridView` with `ObservableCollection<T>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot reorder a `GridView` unless the `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` and `CanReorderItems`, `CanDragItems`, and `AllowDrop` are set to `true`. It is **not** necessary to use a `CollectionViewSource` to enable reordering in your `gridview`. In fact, a `collectionviewsource` is often used for grouping a `gridview` and reordering is not possible when data is grouped.

Anyway, your XAML would look like this:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <GridView CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Although any `enumerable` can be bound to the `ItemsSource` of a `GridView` it is only an `ObservableCollection` that enables reorder. Yes, you can use a custom type that implements reorder, but why mess with that when `ObservableCollection` does it for you?

Your view model might look like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 50))
            Items.Add(item);
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    ObservableCollection<int> m_Items = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get { return m_Items; } }

    object m_ReorderItem;
    int m_ReorderIndexFrom;
    void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                m_ReorderItem = e.OldItems[0];
                m_ReorderIndexFrom = e.OldStartingIndex;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                if (m_ReorderItem == null)
                    return;
                var _ReorderIndexTo = e.NewStartingIndex;
                HandleReorder(m_ReorderItem, m_ReorderIndexFrom, _ReorderIndexTo);
                m_ReorderItem = null;
                break;
        }
    }

    void HandleReorder(object item, int indexFrom, int indexTo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Reorder: {0}, From: {1}, To: {2}", item, indexFrom, indexTo);
    }
}
```

In the code above, the reorder `event` is not real. It is derived from a combination of the "Remove" action and the "Add" action in the `CollectionChanged` event. Here's why this is **awesome**. If the reorder was only available from the `GridView` then the `ViewModel` would not be able to handle it. Because the underlying list is how you detect reorder, the `ViewModel` is enabled.

Every case is slightly different. You may not care about the Index so you can simplify the code. You may not allow adding or removing from the collection so you only need to monitor the Add action. Again, it depends on your situation. My sample code above should get 99% of the cases taken care of.

Remember, `GridView` is not the only control that allows reorder. Any control based on `ListViewBase` (like the `ListView`) supports reorder - still using `ObservableCollection`. But `GridView` is the most common control to use this feature. For sure.

> Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems

**Oh, to answer your question!**

There is no event that indicates a reorder. Reorder is a derived action based on a combination of actions in the underlying `ObservableCollection` `CollectionChanged` event. Make sense?

By the way, here's sample syntax to bind to a `CollectionViewSource`, if you choose to:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CVS" Source="{Binding Items}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <GridView CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}" >
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Been looking for an answer to this all day - this is perfect, just what I needed.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT Inside `Items_CollectionChanged` changed event, how would I handle __adding__ to the collection? Because currently __removing__ followed __adding__ would result in `HandleReorder()`

Comment: Since you can only add through code, you don't really need to listen to your collection, just expand your logic where you add the item.

Comment: This is a nice approach on this topic but i have some questions regarding this. I use this to manipulate some GridViewItems and this method does work but i save the whole Collection from the ObservableCollection for later use and so the user does not load the items again and again. My problem is, the "CollectionChanged" event fires on each itemd added/removed, i would like to have a approach to trigger my method which saves the Collection to storage after all elements have been added/removed. is there a way?

Comment: There is no way to do that without sub-classing ObsCollection