# how can I code different events for Add to Listview and Reorder Listview in Winrt

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am having trouble getting code to fire when a listview has items reordered. I created an event handler for collectionchanged, but that fires when an item is added. I want it only to fire when it is reordered, but reordered in Winrt is a combination of remove and add.

The more general idea of what I want to do is create two listviews of items, where the first listview's items rearrange if corresponding items in the second listview are reordered by the user using drag and drop. I'm pretty close to getting it to work. I have id numbers for elements in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using an observable collection.

Second, read this: [XAML/C#: What event fires after reordering a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388867/xaml-c-what-event-fires-after-reordering-a-gridview)

Best of luck!